# iPhone app recommendation for offline reading

Tags: pdf, offline, iphone-app, rss, reading

I am new to iOS and need some app (free/paid) recommendation for the following:

1. Subscribing to RSS feeds and caching them for offline reads later
2. Reading PDFs which allows increasing font size

These suggestions will really be helpful.

Comment: Perhaps Calibre could do this- unsure but worth a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

No idea about RSS, but I'm personally use iBooks from Apple itself to read PDF files. Is has some nice ideas like switching to black background when the light sensor of your iOS device detects that the surrounding is dark.

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed you said ios. Abobe Acrobat has an ios version. This will allow you to read PDF files.  There is also an app PDF Converter which lets you download and read PDFs on iphone or iPad.  Both of these apps are available from the app store free of charge. I don't know about the RSS feeds.

Answer (score 0):

[Newsblur](http://newsblur.com/) is an RSS reader with offline storage. A free account lets you subscribe to up to 64 sites, above that it is currently $36/year.

[image: Newsblur offline settings]

Answer (score 0):

Byline 5 (free) allows you to cache articles offline from a Feedly account. Be sure to look through the syncing and caching sections of the app settings.

You can turn on webpage syncing for feeds that do not provide article content in their RSS feed.